# sh: 1: rimraf: Permission denied issue on live server

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

Thanks for looking at my issue.

Basically I am facing problem with making build on production dedicated server.

I have executed "npm run build" command and I have received the
the issue

> sh: 1: rimraf: Permission denied issue on live server

I am not sure how exactly we should solve it.

My error logs are as follow below.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v9.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prebuild: @
6 info lifecycle @~build: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/basepath/moneytransfer/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
9 verbose lifecycle @~build: CWD: /var/www/html/basepath/moneytransfer
10 silly lifecycle @~build: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm run clean && webpack --mode development --progress' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~build: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: @ build: `npm run clean && webpack --mode development --progress`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:180:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/basepath/moneytransfer
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v9.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error @ build: `npm run clean && webpack --mode development --progress`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the @ build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried so many solution but nothing worked.But finally removed node_modules folder and executed "npm install" which means re-installation of node modules.And Everything seems working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i rimraf
```

worked for me because I was not in wifi environment. I had a similar error trace (after porting a project with node_modules from windows to mac)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `node_modules` folder seemed to do the trick whenever I was running into such problems!
It is probably caused by different rules related to different file systems; e.g. just different systems or even different operating systems.